how to enable the tiant analysis for the custom quality gate in the soarqube
how to enable the tiant analysis for the custom quality gate in the soarqube
Need help in the procedure on the enabling the taint analysis for the custom quality gate in the SonarQube in detail.Any reference link,docs would be helpful.

Hi there, which edition of SonarQube are you using? Community? Dev? Entreprise?
